# Having trouble using this post category query on multiple pages?

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, page-template

I have three pages on my site (Listen, Read, Watch) which each query a different post category: "listen", "read", and "watch" respectively. I created three separate php files with their own unique template names and I created a Page in the wp-admin and selected the appropriate template for each. I am having trouble using the below query multiple times. For example, Listen page will query the "listen" category successfully with pagination; however, I am unable to use the same code on the other two pages.

```
            <?php
            /*
            Template Name: Listen
            */
            ?>

            <!-- header.php -->
            <?php get_header(); ?>
            <!-- /header.php -->

            <!-- 960 16 Column Grid -->
            <div class="container_16"> 

                <!-- Featured News -->
                <section class="grid_10 read">

                    <!-- Featured News Heading -->
                    <h1></h1>
                    <!-- /Featured News Heading -->

                        <!-- Featured News Loop -->
                        <?php
                            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                                $args=array(
                                    'post_type'=>'post',
                                    'cat' => 'listen',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                    'paged'=>$paged
                                );
                                $temp = $wp_query;
                                $wp_query= null;
                                $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

                            if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { wp_pagenavi(); }
                            if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();
                        ?> 

                        <!-- Post --> 
                        <article class="post">

                            <!-- Featured News Title -->
                            <span><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( '%s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </span>
                            <!-- /Featured News Title -->

                            <!-- Featured News Meta -->
                            <p class="featured-news-post-meta">By <span class="featured-news-author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span> / <?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?>
                            </p>
                            <!-- /Featured News Meta -->

                            <!-- Featured News Thumbnail -->
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(640,320)); ?>
                            <!-- /Featured News Thumbnail -->

                            <!-- Featured News Excerpt -->
                            <p class="featured-news-excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                            <!-- /Featured News Excerpt -->

                            <!-- Featured News Social Links -->
                            <?php include('includes/social.php'); ?>
                            <!-- /Featured News Social Links -->

                        </article>
                        <!-- /Post -->

                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                        <!-- /Featured News Loop -->

                        <!-- Pagination -->
                        <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) : ?>
                            <div class="grid_10 pagination older-news">
                                <?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="arrow">&larr;</span> Older News', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
                                <div class="pagination newer-news">
                                <?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer News <span class="arrow">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <!-- /Pagination -->

                        <?php
                        /* PageNavi at Bottom */
                        if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')){wp_pagenavi();}
                        $wp_query = null;
                        $wp_query = $temp;
                        wp_reset_query();
                        ?>
                        <!-- /Featured News Loop -->

                </section>
                <!-- /Featured News -->

                <!-- Other News -->
                <aside class="grid_5 other-news read-other-news">

                    <!-- Other News Heading -->
                    <h3></h3>
                    <!-- /Other News Heading -->

                        <!-- Other News Loop -->
                        <?php query_posts('category_name=other-news&showposts=6'); ?>
                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <!-- Other News List -->
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="other-news-post-date"><?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y'); ?>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /Other News List -->

                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                        <!-- /Other News Loop -->

                        <!-- View More -->
                        <div class="view-more">
                            <a href="/other-news">View More &rarr;</a>
                        <div>
                        <!-- /View More -->

                </aside>
                <!-- /Other News -->

            </div>
            <!-- /960 16 Column Grid -->

            <!-- sidebar.php -->
            <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            <!-- /sidebar.php -->

            <!-- footer.php -->
            <?php get_footer(); ?>
            <!-- /footer.php -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cat` requires an ID, if you're using the slug, set `category_name` instead. see [WP_Query Category Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters).